# Calculator that accepts floating point values

Tags: android, floating-point, double, calculator

I'm currently learning to use Android Studios, and I'm quite stuck.
The exercise I'm doing is to create a calculator, with the buttons +,-,/. I am done with the calculator, and I've gotten it to work, except for one instance.

Whenever I put in a floating number, even with only one decimal, the program crashes. I experienced this when trying to divide by zero as well, which I solved by surrounding the code with try and catch.

However, I am clueless to what I should to get decimals to work. I would very much appreciate if you could take a look at my code and help me with this issue. My program contains a main java class, and a main xml_class. I'll post them down below:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnAdd,btnSubtract,btnDivide,btnMultiply;
    private TextView tvresult;
    private EditText etfirst, etsecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    btnAdd =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnSubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
    btnDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
    btnMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
    etfirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstNumber);
    etsecond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSecondNumber);
    tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSubtract.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDivide.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    String num1 = etfirst.getText().toString();
    String num2 = etsecond.getText().toString();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            double addition = Double.parseDouble(num1) + 
            Double.parseDouble(num2);
            tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
            break;

        case R.id.btnSubtract:
            double subtraction = Double.parseDouble(num1) - 
            Double.parseDouble(num2);
            tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(subtraction));
            break;

        case R.id.btnMultiply:
            double multiply = Double.parseDouble(num1) * 
            Double.parseDouble(num2);
            tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(multiply));
            break;

        case R.id.btnDivide:
            try {
                double division = Double.parseDouble(num1) /  
                Double.parseDouble(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(division));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                tvresult.setText("Cannot Divide!");
            }
            break;
    }
}       }
}
```

Comment: You could always parse `num1` and `num2` as double (`Double.valueOf`) which works for integers and floating point - the problem then becomes one of formatting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all of

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

to

```
Double.parseDouble()
```

and all of the variable declarations to `double` instead of `int`.
The app crashes with

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

when you try to parse a value like `1.1` to `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for that, how stupid of me to not notice it. I changed all the int's to doubles, as you can see in my edited code above. But it still crashes. What am I missing out on?

Comment: @wznd Does it crash only when you write . ?

Comment: How did you test it? I pasted the code into a new project, and changed the package to the correct name, and no application shows up in my emulator.

Comment: I pasted your code, java and xml to a new project and it works fine except that the layout is full of errors because you did not constraint the views.

Comment: How do I constraint them?

Comment: In design grab the little circles at the left, right, top or bottom and drag them to where you want to be constrained.